# How do I select a random item from an array in ruby (not rails)

Tags: ruby, arrays, random

I have an array of countries:

```
@countries = ["Canada", "Denmark", "Germany", "Isle of Man", "Namibia", "Qatar", "South Africa",  "United Kingdom","United States"]
```

And am building some random data for testing like this:

```
@test = [{ :name   => "AAA -"+Faker::Name.name,  :country => @countries.???? ....}]
```

How do I get a random value from the `@countries` hash?

```
@countries.rand(mlen)
```

does not work and returns `NoMethodError: private method`rand' called for #`.

Comment: For future reference, you should be referring to your data structure of countries as an `array` not a `hash`.

Comment: It's good to be familiar with all the methods in [Array](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array) and [Enumerable](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable). It will save you a lot of effort and make your programs shorter!

Comment: Thanks - I got lost for a while.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

use `Array#sample`:

```
@countries = ["Canada", "Denmark", "Germany", "Isle of Man", "Namibia", "Qatar", "South Africa",  "United Kingdom","United States"]

random_country = @countries.sample
# => "Canada"

random_country = @countries.sample
# => "United Kingdom"
```

Comment: Works great thanks. I tried rand but this is a private method. Ruby has many hidden Gems.

Comment: For Ruby 1.8.7, it's [Array#choice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-choice)

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `random_country = @countries.shuffle.first`.